# Creating a dojo button with in tags

Tags: button, dojo, tags

I am trying to create a dojo button within tags and which is inside a div and the div is inside one of the cell of the datagrid. below is the code i have written

```
'name': 'Value', 
'field': 'mapactions',
'width': '30%',
'editable': false,
'formatter': function (data,rowIndex)
{
    if (data != null)
    {
        var splitStr = data.split("::");

        var tempStr = '<div id="divValue_'+rowIndex+'">'; 

        array.forEach(splitStr, function(item, i)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                tempStr = tempStr+'<div id="cellDiv_divValue_'+rowIndex+'_'+countIncrement+'"  style="padding-top: 25px">'+'<span>'+item+'</span>'+'<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button">Edit</button><button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button">Delete</button></div>';

                parser.parse(); 
            }
            else
            {
                tempStr = tempStr+'<div id="cellDiv_divValue_'+rowIndex+'_'+countIncrement+'"  style="padding-top: 25px">'+'<select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox" style:"width: "75px"; float:"left"; margin: "0px 20px 0px 0px""><option selected>AND</option><option>OR</option></select>'+'<span>'+item+'</span>'+'<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Edit</button>'+'<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Delete</button>'+'</div>';

                parser.parse();
            }           
            countIncrement++;
        }); 


        tempStr = tempStr+'</div>';

        return tempStr;
    }
    else
    {
        return '<div id="divValue_'+rowIndex+'"></div>';
    }   
}
```

all the widgets are created but they do not look as dojo widgets.

Can someone help me in this respect.

Thanks in advance,
Nirmal Kumar Bhogadi

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the dojo/parser into your code after you define the buttons.  Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<title>Template Testing</title>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <script 
        type="text/javascript"
        src="dojo/dojo.js"
        dojoConfig="parseOnLoad:true,isDebug:true" >
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dojo/resources/dojo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dijit/themes/dijit.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

    <style>         
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            font: 12px Myriad, Helvetica, Tahoma, Arial, clean, sans-serif;
        }
    </style>

    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
        require([
        "dojo/dom",
        "dijit/form/Button",
        "dojo/domReady!",
        "dojo/parser"
        ], function(dom, Button, domReady, parser) {                
            dom.byId("myDiv").innerHTML = '<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button">Edit</button>'+'<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button">Delete</button>';
            parser.parse();
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body class="claro">
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
```

If you need more help, go to this [link](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/Button.html#dijit-form-button).

Answer (score 0):

Declarative Dojo markup is only converted to widgets when it's being parsed. Parsing can be done in two ways:

- Manually, using the `dojo/parser` module
- Automatically on DOM load by setting the `parseOnLoad` property in your Dojo config

But since this is dynamically added content, you will have to parse it manually. You can do this by using the following code:

```
require([ "dojo/parser", "dojo/dom" ], function(parser) {
    parser.parse(dom.byId("#test"));
});
```

I suggest you read the [`dojo/parser`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/parser.html) reference guide, it contains a lot of information about widgets and parsing.